# Stack overflow on certain file - Finding positions of sprites

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

First, sorry for my bad english, especially for programming words, english isnt my first language.
So, i have programmed a software that detect all continuous sprites on an image and list their palettes. 
 Full explanation of the software here: https://www.vg-resource.com/thread-33373.html

It works alright, however, if the sprite has at least 4300-ish pixels, a stackoverflow exception is thrown.

In order to find the boundaries of every sprite, first i find the first pixel in the sheet that isnt the color of the background. Then, i start my recursive method that verify every adjacent pixels to see if they dont have the background color, then call itself on that position, their position being recorded in a boolean matrix.
The recursive method:

```
 //pixelPosition > the position found of the current sprite, posX/posY > position of the current pixel being examined
public boolean[][] moveToNextPixel(boolean[][] pixelPosition, int posX, int posY)
{
    pixelPosition[posX][posY] = true;
    //If the next position isnt outside of the boundaries of the image AND if it hasnt already been recorded
    // AND if it isnt the color of the background, move to that position.
    if(posX + 1 < pixelPosition.length)
    {
        if(!pixelPosition[posX+1][posY] && !panBackgroundColor.isColorPresentInPalette(workingImage.getRGB(posX+1,posY)) )
        {
           moveToNextPixel(pixelPosition,posX+1,posY);
        }
    }
    if(posX - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if(!pixelPosition[posX-1][posY] &&  !panBackgroundColor.isColorPresentInPalette(workingImage.getRGB(posX-1,posY)))
        {
            moveToNextPixel(pixelPosition,posX-1,posY);
        }
    }
    if(posY + 1 < pixelPosition[0].length)
    {
        if(!pixelPosition[posX][posY+1] &&  !panBackgroundColor.isColorPresentInPalette(workingImage.getRGB(posX,posY+1)))
        {
            moveToNextPixel(pixelPosition,posX,posY+1);
        }
    }
    if(posY - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if(!pixelPosition[posX][posY-1] && !panBackgroundColor.isColorPresentInPalette(workingImage.getRGB(posX,posY-1)))
        {
            moveToNextPixel(pixelPosition,posX,posY-1);
        }
    }
    return pixelPosition;
}


//the method isColorPresentInPalette(int) check if the color in entry is in the background colors
public boolean isColorPresentInPalette( int colorRgb)
{
    boolean result = false;
    for( int i =0; i< backgroundPalette.length && !result;i++)
    {
        if(backgroundPalette[i] != null)
        {
            if(backgroundPalette[i].getRGB() == colorRgb)
            {
                result = true;    
            }
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Also, if i load a sheet with normal-sized sprite first, and then load one with a huge sprite (4400+ pixels), it doesnt do the stackoverflow error... So, in the end, im pretty confused on what is the problem exactly.
So, is a recursive method really the right way for this kind of problem? If so what could i do to fix this? Otherwise, anyone see a way to determine each individuals continuous sprites and their positions?

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but it will speed up `isColorPresentInPalette()` if you replace `result = true` with `return true`. There's no reason to keep running the loop once you've found the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: Originally I posted a recursive solution but didn't realize that you were doing that. I think after reading more carefully, it seems Recursion might not be the best since you will be adding so many calls given 4300 pixels.

I would just do DFS in memory in this case then. Alternatively, you might try BFS (which will search outwards from the center).

An example of DFS in memory. This basically does the same thing as the recursion above except instead of storing things on the callstack which has a limited buffer size, you would be storing memory:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Stack;

public class FindNeedleInHaystack {

    String[][] haystack;

    class Coordinate {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Coordinate that = (Coordinate) o;
            return x == that.x &&
                    y == that.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }
    }

    public FindNeedleInHaystack() {
        this.haystack = new String[10][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                this.haystack[i][j] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    public void addNeedle(int a_x, int a_y) {
        this.haystack[a_y][a_x] = "needle";
    }

    public boolean hasNeedle() {
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[10][10];
        return hasNeedleHelper(0, 0);

    }

    private List<Coordinate> neighbors(Coordinate coord, boolean[][] visited) {
        List<Coordinate> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
        int x = coord.x;
        int y = coord.y;
        if (y + 1 < 10 && !visited[y+1][x]) neighbors.add(new Coordinate(x, y+1));
        if (y - 1 >= 0 && !visited[y-1][x]) neighbors.add(new Coordinate(x, y-1));
        if (x + 1 < 10 && !visited[y][x+1]) neighbors.add(new Coordinate(x + 1, y));
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && !visited[y][x-1]) neighbors.add(new Coordinate(x - 1, y));
        return neighbors;
    }

    private boolean hasNeedleHelper(int x, int y) {
        Stack<Coordinate> fringe = new Stack<>();
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[10][10];

        fringe.push(new Coordinate(x, y));
        while(!fringe.isEmpty()) {
            Coordinate toVisit = fringe.pop();
            if (this.haystack[toVisit.y][toVisit.x].equals("needle")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                visited[toVisit.y][toVisit.x] = true;
                for(Coordinate coord : this.neighbors(toVisit, visited)) {
                    fringe.push(coord);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String...args) {
        FindNeedleInHaystack hasNeedle = new FindNeedleInHaystack();
        hasNeedle.addNeedle(3, 4);
        System.out.println("Has a needle?: " + hasNeedle.hasNeedle());

        FindNeedleInHaystack doesntHaveNeedle = new FindNeedleInHaystack();
        System.out.println("Has a needle?: " + doesntHaveNeedle.hasNeedle());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, however i am keeping the position of where ive already examined.  At the start of the recursive method, i set the current position ( "pixelPosition", which is a boolean[][])  at true. Before going to the next pixel, i always verify that  "pixelPosition" isnt true at the examining position.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't read your code as closely as I should've. Apologies.  Well, one way of testing it out is if instead of doing it recursively, just use a Stack to do DFS. I'll write an example and show you how that works.